# Flask with PyInstaller does not show images added at runtime

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller

I have a simple app running on ***Flask***, which displays images from a directory. Which works fine, until I create an executable using ***Pyinstaller***. This executable also works when there were already some images at the time of creation, but it can't load any later added images, I guess it just bundles all the existing images. I tried with both a single file and a directory, nothing worked.
I would be really grateful if somebody can give me some direction on this.

This is the html file:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
   
<body>
    <h1>Output page</h1>
    <img id="im" src="{{ url_for('static', filename=image) }}" />
</body>
<script>
    var img = document.getElementById('im');
    console.log('img.src: ' + img.src);
</script>
</html>
```

This is the server code:

```
import os
import requests
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

image_no_ = 0

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def show_image():
    global image_no_

    files = os.listdir('static/images')

    new_image = 'static/images/'+files[image_no_]
    print ('image path:', new_image)
    image_no_ += 1
    if image_no_ == len(files):
        image_no_ = 0

    return render_template("index.html", image=new_image)  

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)
```

This is my pyinstaller spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['test.py'],
             pathex=['/home/danish/Downloads/danish/code/TestFlask'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('templates/index.html', 'templates/'), ('static/images', 'static/images')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='test',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found two issues in the above code.

1. When bundled, pyinstaller executable gets a runtime local path, which is stored in *sys._MEIPASS*, So any file access has to go through that path.
2. Flask by default use static as the folder to access images, but now our path is changed so we need to add a new route to access those files:

Now the code looks like this:-

HTML:

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Output page</h1>
    <img id="im" src="{{ url_for('images', filename=image) }}" />
    <button id="button" type="button" on_click=click()>next</button>
</body>
<script>
    var img = document.getElementById('im');
    console.log('img.src: ' + img.src);
</script>
</html>
```

Server code:

```
import os
import sys
import requests
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

image_no_ = 0

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = ""
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/images/<path:filename>')
def images(filename):
    valid_file_formats = ['.jpg', '.png', '.bmp']
    base_path = ""
    if filename[-4:] in valid_file_formats:
        base_path = resource_path('static/data')
    return send_from_directory(base_path, filename)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def show_image():
    global image_no_

    files_path = resource_path('static/data')
    files = os.listdir(files_path)
    new_image = files[image_no_]

    image_no_ += 1
    if image_no_ == len(files):
        image_no_ = 0

    return render_template("index.html", image=new_image)  

if __name__=='__main__':
    print ('Base Path:', sys._MEIPASS)
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)
```

Will have to manager a not in pyintaller's spec file aswell.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution would be to just copy your static, templates and images folder during the `pyinstaller` build.

```
pyinstaller -w -F --add-data "templates;templates" --add-data "static;static" --add-data "images;images" app.py
```